# Sending data from outside socket object in python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, stack

I made a `Client` socket object, which I instantiate and it keeps alive a connection with the server, which is working fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way to call the `socket.send` event from outside the instance. I was about to make a stack for the messages and check the stack in the while loop and if it's not empty then send the oldest data to the server, which would be just fine for me, but my problem is that the stack only updates  after the while loop(I tried breaking out, then it updated).
So my question would be, is there a way to update the global stack simultaneously with the while loop running? Or is there any other way to call the `socket.send` event outside the object?

```
import socket
import sys
import select
import threading

SERVER_IP = '192.168.1.4'
PORT = 8686
TIMEOUT = 5
BUF_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGES = ['testdata1', 'testdata2']

class Client(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, host=SERVER_IP, port=PORT):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), 1)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)
        while 1:
            try:
                global MESSAGES
                ready = select.select([self.sock], [], [], TIMEOUT*1000)
                if ready[0]:
                    buf = self.sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                    print buf
                    #TODO:do stuff with buf

                    print 'messages left:'+str(len(MESSAGES))
                    if len(MESSAGES)>0:
                        self.sock.send(MESSAGES.pop())
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.sock.close()
                sys.exit(1)
            except Exception, e:
                print '\n[ERR] %s' % e
                self.sock.close()
                sys.exit(1)

    def run(self):
        pass

    def sendData(self, data):
        global MESSAGES
        print 'appending data:%s' % data
        MESSAGES.append(data)

def main():
    client = Client()
    client.start()
    client.sendData("test1")
    client.sendData("test2")
    client.sendData("test3")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Client.__init__()` does not return because it enters an infinite while loop. Hence control is never returned to the main thread, and the `Client` thread is not actually started.

Instead you should move the while loop into the `run()` method. Then the `__init__()` method will return control to the main thread, which can then start the thread, and request that the client send messages via `sendData()`.

```
class Client(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, host=SERVER_IP, port=PORT):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), 1)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                global MESSAGES
                ready = select.select([self.sock], [], [], TIMEOUT*1000)
                if ready[0]:
                    buf = self.sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                    print buf
                    #TODO:do stuff with buf

                    print 'messages left:'+str(len(MESSAGES))
                    if len(MESSAGES)>0:
                        self.sock.send(MESSAGES.pop())
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.sock.close()
                sys.exit(1)
            except Exception, e:
                print '\n[ERR] %s' % e
                self.sock.close()
                sys.exit(1)

    def sendData(self, data):
        global MESSAGES
        print 'appending data:%s' % data
        MESSAGES.append(data)
```

Instead of using the global `MESSAGES` list you should probably create a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue) for communicating between the main thread and the worker thread(s), particularly if more than one worker thread is running. Something like this (untested!):

```
import Queue

class Client(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, msg_queue, host=SERVER_IP, port=PORT):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.msg_queue = msg_queue
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock = socket.create_connection((host, port), 1)
        self.sock.setblocking(0)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            try:
                ready = select.select([self.sock], [], [], TIMEOUT*1000)
                if ready[0]:
                    buf = self.sock.recv(BUF_SIZE)
                    print buf
                    #TODO:do stuff with buf

                    print 'messages left:'+ str(self.msg_queue.qsize())
                    try:
                        msg = self.msg_queue.get_nowait()
                        self.sock.send(msg)
                    except Queue.Empty:
                        pass
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                self.sock.close()
                sys.exit(1)
            except Exception, e:
                print '\n[ERR] %s' % e
                self.sock.close()
                sys.exit(1)

def main():
    # create a queue and pass it to the client
    msg_queue = Queue.Queue()
    client = Client(msg_queue)
    client.start()
    msg_queue.put("test1")
    msg_queue.put("test2")
    msg_queue.put("test3")
```

Comment: As your answer contains the same info as mine, but you added some code, please consider adding code without select as well, as I proposed.  Or I will add it to my answer. Or else using Queue() for speed doesn't make too much sense for speeding up the thing. I think this is a small client app, so difference between these data types wouldn't matter much. But bothering OS with unnecessary system calls will increase CPU usage.

Comment: @Dalen : well, my answer contains _some_ of the same info as yours, but mine does go further to suggest a thread safe way of communicating between the main thread and (potentially) multiple worker threads. This is a better architecture going forward, and certainly better than using a global variable. Regarding speed, what is the issue? The OP didn't mention one, and `Queue` is not slow.

Comment: @Dalen: regarding the use of `select()` within the thread is not, as you say, ideal. In this example it would be better to simply perform a blocking `recv()`, although it is not difficult to imagine that the main thread might want to send messages to the worker thread to control it, e.g. a quit command. In that case use of `select()` is not an unreasonable, and for that reason I will leave my answer as it is.

Comment: I agree, but as I explained, it is not an issue of the client's speed. It just makes one system call more than necessary. select() is fast, yes, but why bothering OS first with syscall, then select() itself checks the socket over and over for 5 seconds. If TIMEOUT is smaller, select() bothers socket less, but we bother OS more. As for thread safe, well, first, I'd advice the OP not to store messages in a global variable if possible. And second, there is only one listener registered, and no reuse_addr(), and global msgs. That's why I assumed that there will be always only one Client() per app.

Comment: Yes, this concept will work, if you want to send data, but if nonblocking mode is used, recv() is, well, nonblocking. That means that timeout can be much smaller than 5 seconds, so we can send data at any time, and receive data faster. And OS is free but for a socket. I think that OS performs something similar to select() anyway, when socket is in non blocking mode. But as it is all in C and direct on our socket it is better for all. Well I think that that's enough on this subject. I feel that I am boring you all. :D Just good intentions for further improvements.

Comment: This comment before is perhaps a little confusing. I ment that recv() in non blocking mode can be used without select to check in advance. Either it raises an error or returns None if there is no data to be returned. Not sure at the mo.  I'll check.

Comment: @Dalen: Calling `select()` is perfectly reasonable and efficient, and the duration of the timeout makes no practical difference to the load. Note that `select()` does not "check over and over" as though in a busy loop. Another option is to set a timeout with `socket.settimeout()`.

Comment: @Dalen:  SO_REUSEADDR applies to servers, not clients, so that is not an issue here.

Comment: @Dalen: Using non-blocking sockets is worse. It effectively requires a busy loop. Adding a `sleep()` system call to add a delay is a poor substitute for `select()` because `select()` also indicates that status of the file descriptor - `sleep()` tells you nothing. This might free the OS (not that it's overly burdened by select), but the work is now performed (less efficiently) in user space, not the kernel.

Comment: How do you know? Did you see the code? Are you an implementer of select() for any OS? I am sorry, but select() suffers from the same illness as any other system call.

Comment: That is, that it raises the software interrupt to get the result from the OS kernel. When kernel is done with this operation, and any other it decides to do, it jumps back to user space and returns the info to our process. Too much  jumping back and forth, and CPU, and OS and its scheduler are in overload. Make your OS write some string into a file to a HD in a busy loop. It'll slow down drasticly. Any other efficiency of select() aside, this is enough for me tonot use it in this manner. No need for extra calls. Socket is enough.

Comment: I don't think so. sleep() is one system call that tells OS scheduler to return to our process when the specified time expires. At least on OSes should be so. If it is not, well, then, I am disapointed. sleep() doesn't return us anything, but recv() does, data or no data.

Comment: Woops, sorry, I was careless, overlooked create_connection(). Just didn't see sock.connect() and in my head Client automatically became server. That's why I mentioned automatically reuse_addr(). Lesson for future. Sorry.

Comment: @Dalen: Seriously?  A recv on a non-blocking socket will return immediately with an error if there was no data to read. Then what? Your code is either in a tight loop (akin to your writing to HD example), or you need to introduce a delay. `sleep()` can provide that delay but, being a system call, it "suffers from the same illness" as `select()` in that, oh no,  it switches to kernel mode and back as required.  Neither of us really know the nitty gritty of the implementation, and we don't need to - this is Python, and the focus should be on readable code, not micro-optimisations.

Comment: @Dalen: just use `socket.settimeout()` and use blocking sockets.

Comment: Yes sir! For remembering about socket timeouts, and nitty gritty (hehe) comment I'll upvote your A. Yeah, yeah, but nice code means using list and threading.Lock() instead of Queue(). It's readable. You can see what exactly is when happening. Who minds that list.pop(0) is inefficient? Sometimes you have to think about micro-optimization, even if it is Python.

Comment: @Dalen: thanks for the upvote, but I can't agree with you that lists and locks are in any way nicer than a `Queue`. A queue is perfect for this scenario and hides the ugly, and bug prone, use of locks.

Comment: You earned it!  This is only a point of view. (About readability and uglyness).

Answer (score 1):

The thing should work if you move your loop from

```
__init__() into run()
```

method instead.

Your thread is not a thread this way, process blocks at client = Client(...).

Why do you mix select and threads? Is this really necessary? If you want asynchronous sending and receiving without threads use asyncore module.
Or remove select from your code. The socket.recv() will block until it receives  data in blocking mode, but as this is a thread, I don't see anything wrong about that. If in nonblocking mode, recv() will just return None if there is no data to receive if I remember correctly. So you don't really need select. Just check if recv() returned None. If it does, sleep some time before trying again.

The way you did it troubles  your OS twice. Once for reading a socket, and second time to get the status of a socket where timeout is used to simulate sleep() more than anything else. Then the loop checks again  making select() system call right after timeout confirmed that there is nothing to do for that socket.